# Form Always Empty

Tags: go, web

I've been building a Go todo list and I'm trying to add the ability to add new items, but every time I access the form value, it comes out empty. Here's the handler I built:

```
func addHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    cook, _ := r.Cookie("userid")
    id := cook.Value
    r.ParseForm()
    text := r.FormValue("todo")
    addTodo(text,id) //inserts into database
    http.Redirect(w,r,"/todo",http.StatusFound)
}
```

And here's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    {{range .}}
    <tr><td>{{printf "%s" .Text}}</td><td><a href="/delete/{{.ID}}">delete</a></td></tr>
    {{end}}
</table>
<form action="/add" method="post"><input type="text" name="todo"><button type="submit">Add</button></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think calling `ParseForm` multiple times does anything, and actually `FormValue` calls ParseForm itself so you don't have to call it manually at all, at least not in this case. That said, did you try `log.Println(r.Form)`?? is it empty? Do you have any middleware setup in front of your `addHandler`?

Comment: Nothing in front of my `addHandler` besides other `addHandlers`. `log.Println(r.Form)` returns an empty map.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you're registering the handler? The http.HandleFunc part... also, did you check the browser console? Is the form being sent correctly with the correct Content-Type header?

Comment: `func main() {
     http.HandleFunc("/",loginHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/todo/",todoHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/delete/",deleteHandler)
     http.HandleFunc("/add/",addHandler)
     http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil)
   }`

Comment: The only thing that seems off is that you're not checking the error returned from `r.Cookie`, because if no cookie with the name `userid` was sent then your `addHandler` would result in a panic when trying to access `cook.Value`... Other than that your code, including the html form seems ok to me, and in fact i was able to reconstruct a tiny program from your example code and it works just fine (with the cookie code commented out). If your handler is not panicking on the `cook.Value` line then you must be doing something wrong somewhere not in the code you've provided.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kind of at a loss. Commenting out the cookie code does nothing. I have another page that's a simple login page and I've had no issues with it. I even checked the header, and the text is in there. Really weird.